# AWS route53 forwarding

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I'm trying to setup a SAAS with the following URL configuration:

www.mysite.com/ --> forward to www.mysite.com/site

www.mysite.com/site --> company public page hosted on S3

All of the other URLs should point to EC2 servers where my SAAS is running on NGINX and PHP. How can I configure this?  Ideally, I'd like the users accessing the company public page to avoid hitting the nginx servers and go directly to the S3 hosting.  Is that possible?  I'd like to use AWS Route53, ELB and Cloudfront.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, main goals is:

"Forwarding root to a subdirectory is not the main part of the question. I want to forward a subdirectory to S3 and everything else to AWS ELB."

This could be done in different way, you can create 2 DNS records like:

- www.test.com
- api.test.com

www.test.com could be static part of the site (hosted on S3)

api.test.com could point to LBs (1+). Behind LB you can have AutoScaling group for your application

Answer (score 0):

**Hello there.**
I am not aware of any ways of redirecting root to subdirectory using only DNS. Would be nice to know if there is.

I also dont think it is really overwhelming for nginx to do a permanent redirect using rewrite. Is there a special reason why you dont want the requests to www.mysite.com to hit nginx and go straight to www.mysite.com/site?

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule

```
location = / {
    rewrite "^$" /site;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  The only reason was to reduce the load on the  app server.  I was hoping to use S3 as the web server and EC2 as the app server.  Forwarding root to a subdirectory is not the main part of the question.  I want to forward a subdirectory to S3 and everything else to AWS ELB.

Comment: I dont see how you can do that. The only way I see is all traffic goes do ELB, ELB directs to nginx server and nginx do the rest. Now, all to ELB and one subdirectory to s3 I dont see how. Why dont you do a cname? static.yourdomain.com? But wait maybe someone can come up with a anwser. I am no expert on this. Best regards and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a separate domain for the page hosted on S3. You could drop the `www` or replace it with `www-2` and make that domain name point to your S3 hosted site while `www.mysite.com` continues to point to your ELB.